# Sometimes $_POST return empty results after form submission

Tags: php, html, forms, post, isset

I have an HTML form and I use `isset` to check if `POST` variables are set, then I process them (send them via email or to a Google Spreadsheet). *Sometimes* I receive empty result(s), like if the variable(s) is/are null or empty, not even an empty space. Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

```
 <?php if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["tel"])){
      $name  = $_POST["name"];
      $phone  = $_POST["phone"];
      $message="Name: $name \nPhone : $phone \n";

      require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

      $mail = new PHPMailer;
      $mail->setFrom('from@mail.com', 'From Name');
      $mail->addAddress('to@gmail.com', 'To Name');
      $mail->Subject  = 'Message Subject';
      $mail->Body     = $message; ?>

 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" method="post">                     
     <input id="name" type="text" name="name" title="Enter your name" placeholder="Name" required >      
     <input id="phone" type="phone" name="phone" pattern="0(6|5)([-. ]?[0-9]{2}){4}" title="Enter your phone" placeholder="Phone" required >
     <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Send</button>                      
 </form>
```

**P.S.** The fields may have RTL Arabic entries sometimes. I'm also using client-side Javascript validation to check if the fields are valid and not empty. I understand that client-side validation can be flooded since it's client-side and since browsers are different from each other, however, I can't figure out how empty entries are still returning `true` from `if(isset($_POST[])`! Is that a normal behaviour of `isset($_POST[])` when the `input` fields are empty? Will checking if `!empty($_POST[])` be correct and relevant in my case?
.

Answer (score 2):

isset() just checks that the variable is set and not NULL.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

If it's set and empty, isset() returns TRUE.

You need to use empty() to check for an empty value.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

You can also do a strict check against the value if you know what to check against:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] !== '')
```